# RHEL 6 conf.modules.d not existing

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, configuration

I want to change the SSO of my application and need a httpd server for authentication via Keycloack. Now the problem is that when I install the httpd I don't have the conf.modules.d directory, which exists on my PROD system (RHEL 7).
Does the httpd server work when I move or copy the directory from my RHEL 7 system or can I install the conf.modules.d afterwards?

When trying to start the server, it will notice that it can't find the conf.modules.d and needs it for starting.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No, the default RHEL6 `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` does not include this line:

```
 Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

That is the line that is in RHEL7's default [httpd.conf](https://git.centos.org/rpms/httpd/blob/c7/f/SOURCES/httpd.conf#_56), and what includes all the files in the conf.modules.d/ directory.

You could always add a file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ (that ends with .conf) that would have the aforementioned `Include`, but be sure that it is loaded before any conf files that rely on modules being loaded.

Comment: So you mean just put the config files into the conf.modules.d and then proceed as you have described. How can I make sure that this config file is loaded first?

Comment: They’re loaded alphabetically (assuming LANG=C).

Comment: So what should be the name for the config file something with letter a or what can you recommend?

Comment: @user431918 or a number 0